# how can i put the el-upload file into an jsonObject,and revieve them into multipartFile

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, file, element-ui, multipartfile

I want to give springboot the object(form-data or jsonobject) which contains some el-upload file,because i want to organize them into specific data-structure,so i don't want to upload files only.